# How does Jest output rich text to IDE console?

Tags: intellij-idea, jestjs

I'm using [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) in my project and it creates a very neat console output. (I'm using JIdea 2017 in RHEL 6.9)

I'd like to know how Jest actually does that? How can we print something to the console like that, with colored text, colored backgrounds, etc.

[image]

Comment: Potentially by using ANSI escape codes.

Answer (score 1):

It uses https://github.com/chalk/chalk

From the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/ab6f4c3001a2cd917cc4df95e42dfc72f23c5a00/packages/jest-cli/src/reporters/get_result_header.js#L20-L21):

```
const FAIL = chalk.reset.inverse.bold.red(' FAIL ');
const PASS = chalk.reset.inverse.bold.green(' PASS ');
```

Comment: @prime Do know if there is a Java equivalent. There are many Java libraries that can color the output, but maybe not the way chalk does.

Comment: Any suggestions for the Java libs ?

I just tried ANSI escape codes in eclipse now, but not working

Comment: Found this for an instance, but didn't try it https://github.com/fusesource/jansi